How to get values from enumeration created from ExchangeManagement Shell
How to get the AccessRights List for the identity in C Sharp.
where I tried to cast the
obj.Properties["AccessRights"].Value to PSObject,PSObject[],object etc..\
But everything resulted in Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.MailboxRights[] cannot be casted.
and I'm specifically using Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
String execCommand = "Get-MailboxPermission -Identity \"{OBJECT_GUID}\"";
results = executeCommand(execCommand,ref errString);

foreach (PSObject obj in results) {
\\ get the list of accessrights here
\\ obj.Properties["AccessRights"].Value;
}


What do you mean "cannot be casted" - what happens when you try (Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.MailboxRights[])obj.Properties["AccessRights"].Value? Have you inspected the runtime type of the property value? eg. obj.Properties["AccessRights"].Value.GetType()

it gives a compilation error
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Exchange' does not exist in the namespace
'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I would get the code working in Powershell first which I think would be easier to debug.  In the foreach loop I would use $obj | format-table  which will dump the obj so you can see the properties.  In PS to get the types I like using Write-Host "PropertyName" $obj.propertyname.GetType()

the type is ArrayList in the powershell but in c sharp it is treated as Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.MailboxRights[]

You can cast the AccessRights Properties to Array and so you will get the result from the 1st element of the array.
Array accessRights = (obj.Properties["AccessRights"].Value as Array);
String result = accessRights.GetValue(0).ToString();

by using this way no need to cast the AccessRights Properties to Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.MailboxRights[].
